# MediaRecorder, I can't write on SDcard

Tags: android

I want to record voice in android, and I try to develop a small application for testing, so wen I run my application it told me that I can't write on the sdcard, so there is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private static final String LOG_TAG_ENREGISTREUR = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button record_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button stop_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        File fileRecord = null;
        final MediaRecorder media = new MediaRecorder();
        String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){

            Log.e(LOG_TAG_ENREGISTREUR,"SDcard not found!");
            return;
        }

        File repertoryStockage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if(!repertoryStockage.canWrite()){

            Log.e(LOG_TAG_ENREGISTREUR,"Impossible , you can't write");

            return;
        }

        try {

            fileRecord = File.createTempFile("RecordingAudio", ".mp4",repertoryStockage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG_ENREGISTREUR,"Probleme E/S before recording");
            return;
        }
        media.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        media.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        media.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        media.setOutputFile(fileRecord.getAbsolutePath());

        record_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    media.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                media.start();

            }
        });

        stop_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                media.stop();
                media.release();

            }
        });
    }



}
```

and i add permissions in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

an other thing I create a SDcard and I add it to emulator by : -sdcard "[Path of sdcard]"
so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this code works for me.. so might be something that you configured wrong in your emulator. I used SDK level 15 (4.0.3).

You could try replacing the `try` block with the Log that says `Impossible, You can't write` to this one:

```
File repertoryStockage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File sample = new File(repertoryStockage,"empty.txt"); 
try
{
    sample.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(!sample.canWrite()){

    Log.e(LOG_TAG_ENREGISTREUR,"Impossible , you can't write");
    return;
}
sample.delete();
```

I found some places indicating that you cannot check for write permission on a directory.
see this answer (the code is mainly from that answer): [Checking for write access in a directory before creating files inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272130/checking-for-write-access-in-a-directory-before-creating-files-inside-it)

But as I said in the beginning, the code works for me, without any changes.

Comment: I checked DDMS > mnt > sdcard and I found that there are no permissions to write or to read, so have you any idea how to change it? I think this was the problem

Comment: Oh thank you for your answer, the problem was like I say before "SDCARD WITHOUT PERMISSIONS" so I follow this [link](http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html), And I solved the problem