# How to make Java list only writable files

Tags: java, file

I need to know how to know how to make Java's File.list(); method list only the files I am able to access or how to filter them out, cause now it lists files like $RecycleBin or Documents and Settings (I am on Win7) basically files I am unable to see in Win Explorer. Many Thanks.

Comment: I think there are methods such as canRead and canWrite in the File object

Comment: I think i tried that a a while ago and it didn't really work. I'll try again to be sure.

Comment: Yup, it only works with files, not folders.

Comment: take a look on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do it:

```java
File[] subDirs = dir.listFiles( new FileFilter() {
  @Override public boolean accept( File f ) {
    return f.canWrite();
  } } );
```

You could also use `CanWriteFileFilter` of `apache.commons.io` (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/CanWriteFileFilter.html)

*Example, showing how to print out a list of the current directory's writable files:*

```java
 File dir = new File(".");
 String[] files = dir.list( CanWriteFileFilter.CAN_WRITE );
 for ( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
     System.out.println(files[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Well, your solution works for files but not folders. Is there a way to do it? Thanks

Comment: The Java Class `File` is a representation of file and directory pathnames. You can for instance ask if it is a directory `f.isDirectory()` or is a file `f.isFile()` and much more. Please feel free to read the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: I know you can ask it if it is a Directory or a File. Though I am not sure how to ask it if there is any readable file in a folder or if I can access the folder itself.

Comment: I used isHidden() and it has actually removed a bunch more of the files. I think it is gonna be enough. Thanks guys!

Comment: @ArkayCZ Well, you didn't ask that in your original question. Please refer to the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272130/checking-for-write-access-in-a-directory-before-creating-files-inside-it

Comment: Well, I didn't know... :D