# Issue with checking permission of a folder in java

Tags: java

I am creating simple function to check weather I have write/delete permission to a folder

**I want to know whether the operating system will allow writing into the folder or not ?**

```
public static String PermissionCheck(String FilePath) {
    //File f = new File(FilePath);
    String actions = "read,write";
    try 
    {
      AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission(FilePath, actions));
      return ("You have read/write permition to use : " + FilePath);
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) 
    {
      return ("You don't have read/write permition to use : " + FilePath);
    }
}
```

When I call either with correct path or incorrect path the method it always returns message from cathc.

I know its duplicate question I have already gone through many links but no luck !!

[**Similar Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272130/checking-for-write-access-in-a-directory-before-creating-files-inside-it)

[**Similar Question 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231779/how-to-check-write-permissions-of-a-directory-in-java)

**Example :**

```
PreChecks.PermissionCheck("C:/TEST/G2");
PreChecks.PermissionCheck("C:/Program Files/SAP");
```

Both calls return the message from catch block where I have all permission on "C:/TEST/G2" and no write permission on "C:/Program Files/SAP".

**I have also tried canWrite but it says I have write permissions to "C:/Program Files/SAP" but I know I don't have those.**

Comment: What is the Exception ? Can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: It would certainly help if you provided the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Not exception always the message from catch block.

Comment: Obviosly, you need to print the stack trace for a stack trace to appear... Try to add e.printStackTrace() to the catch block. I do however suspect that your problem might be related to not having configured a securitymanager and proper permissions, or that you infact are not testing what you intend to. AccessController.checkPermissions are checking JVM security manager permissions, which is not the same as filesystem permissions.

Comment: You are printing "You don't have read/write permition to use..." for any `SecurityException`, while the actual cause of the exception may be different. Print the message and the stack trace of the actual exception instead. Why are you inferring the cause of the exception yourself?

Comment: @NilsH : Is there any other better way to check the folder permissions ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve, do you want to know whether the `SecurityManager` grants access (as your code suggests) or do you want to know whether the operating system will allow writing into the folder as the questions you have linked suggest?

Comment: I want to know whether the operating system will allow writing into the folder or not ?

Comment: You might be looking for `canExecute`, `canRead` and `canWrite` in [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: I have also tried canWrite but it says I have write permissions to "C:/Program Files/SAP" but i don't have those.

Comment: Abdul, replace the code in the catch block with `e.printStackTrace` to actually see what the exception raised is. There is an exception, you are hiding it from yourself by not printing it in the catch block.

Comment: So why don’t you use what you have linked, e.g. `try { sample.createNewFile(); sample.delete(); } catch(IOException e) { /* here you know you don’t have access*/ }`

Comment: @Zoltán: that doesn’t help as querying the `SecurityManager` is the completely wrong approach.

Comment: @Holger : I just want to check weather i am allowed to create the files inside a directory or not , I just need the return message.

Answer (score 1):

The class `java.io.File` is limited in its capabilities. E.g.

```
File f=new File("C:\\Program Files\\Java");
System.out.println(f.canWrite());
```

prints `true` on my machine though a user process is not allowed to write at this location.

In contrast,

```
Path p=Paths.get("C:\\Program Files\\Java");
System.out.println(Files.isWritable(p));
```

correctly prints `false`.

So the solution is to use the NIO API.

---

The method `AccessController.checkPermission` has an entirely different purpose. It helps implementing security managers. It throws a `SecurityException` because you don’t have an explicitly granted permission to access that directory, but as long as you don’t have a `SecurityManager` installed, that is irrelevant.